# Moving from one java class to another in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

While clicking on the button in the contact1.class, the datas are inserting into the database. Which means, the query is executing and the program is running fine upto ps.execute();. After that, the language class that I have called is not opening properly. In the sense, the frame is opening with a white background color. But, if I'm calling it through my main method;it's working fine and if I'm skipping this class too, the project will work smoothly.

This is my contact1.java class

```
public class Contact1 implements ActionListener{

 boolean clicked=false;
        JFrame jf; 
      JLabel  lblName,lblEmail;
      JTextField txtName,txtPhone;
      JButton btnSave;
      JPanel p1;
     GridLayout gl42;
    FlowLayout fl;
    static Dimension dim=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    static int w=(int)dim.getWidth();    static int h=(int)dim.getHeight();
        int xpos=(int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()/2-215;
        int ypos=(int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()/2-215;


@SuppressWarnings("LeakingThisInConstructor")
    public Contact1() throws IOException{

        jf=new JFrame("THE COUNTRY CLUB");

          jf.setSize(w,h);
          jf.setVisible(true);
          jf.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
          jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        //jf.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("D:/workspace/Crorepati/Images/bg.jpg")))));         
          lblName= new JLabel("Name");
          lblNo= new JLabel("Contact No");
          txtName=new JTextField(40);
          txtPhone=new JTextField(40);
          btnSave=new JButton("Play Game");
              txtName.setBounds(xpos,ypos,50,40);
              btnSave.setActionCommand("Play Game");
              btnSave.addActionListener(this);
          p1=new JPanel();

           p1.add(lblName);
           p1.add(txtName);
           p1.add(lblNo);
           p1.add(txtPhone);
           p1.add(btnSave);


           jf.add(p1);

           jf.setVisible(true);
    }


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
Contact1 a1 = new Contact1();
}
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent a)
    {
    String name = txtName.getText();
    String contact = txtPhone.getText();
    try
    {

   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:details");
   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into details (Name,Contact) values (?,?)");
   ps.setString(1,name);
   ps.setString(2,contact);       
   ps.execute();
   txtName.setText("");
   txtPhone.setText("");

  // Language.main(new String []{"A"});
   Language language = new Language();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    }
```

This is my second class named Language.java

```
 public class Language extends JPanel {

JFrame jf;
LanguageSelect l = new LanguageSelect();
English eng = new English();
Arabic arab = new Arabic();  


 public Language() {
    try{
        buildGUI();
        perform();
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

public void buildGUI() throws Exception{

      jf=new JFrame("THE COUNTRY CLUB");

      Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      Dimension dim=t.getScreenSize();
      int width=(int)dim.getWidth();  int height=(int)dim.getHeight();


      JLayeredPane jlp1=new JLayeredPane(),
                              jlp2=new JLayeredPane(),
                              jlp3=new JLayeredPane();

      Box panelbox=new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

      jlp1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jlp1,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
      jlp2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      jlp3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

      jlp1.add(BorderLayout.EAST,new LogoPanel());
    //  jlp1.add(BorderLayout.WEST,d);

      jlp3.add(eng);jlp3.add(arab);
      jlp3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1250,160));

      panelbox.add(jlp1);panelbox.createVerticalStrut(200);
      panelbox.add(l);
      panelbox.add(jlp3);

      jf.getContentPane().add(panelbox);

      jf.setSize(width,height);
      jf.setVisible(true);
      jf.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
      jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void perform()throws Exception{

    while ((eng.clicked==false)&&(arab.clicked==false) )
    {

    }

    if(eng.clicked==true) 
    {
    if(eng.optiona.equals("English")) 
    {    
    eng.repaint(); 
    Run_Project.main();                            
    }
    }
    else if(arab.clicked==true)
    {
    if(arab.optiona.equals("Arabic")) 
    {
    arab.repaint(); 
    Run_Project1.main();                         
    }

    }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
        new Language();
    }
```

I don't have an idea of what's happening here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've probably got a Swing threading issue where your Swing event thread is locked up by long running code that is not being run in a background thread, but it's hard to tell based on the code you've posted. Consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also consider improving the formatting of code you post, especially the indentation.

Comment: Before the given piece of code, I have declared all the textfields, buttons and frame in both the classes. Which class is insufficient here? If needed, I can provide rest of the codes too.

Comment: `Run_Project.main(new String []{"A"});` ???

Comment: @peeskillet: That's an another class and I have modified it. Please have a look.

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: This is all what I have in my classes